# Surat Al-Mutaffifin [83:22-25] says the righteous will be given to drink wine, what does it mean?

Tags: quran, tafseer, alcohol

I'm not Muslim, so I can miss something obvious here. Reading the Quran I found that piece: http://quran.com/83/22

The translation is:

> Indeed, the righteous will be in pleasure
>   On adorned couches, observing.
>   You will recognize in their faces the radiance of pleasure.
>   They will be given to drink [pure] wine [which was] sealed.

What is "a pure wine"? And why the righteous would drink it, considering sobriety is a virtue and all kinds of intoxication are denounced and forbidden, aren't they?

Comment: They drink it (if they want to) as it is it will be allowed in paradise and no more prohibited!

Comment: @Medi1Saif are there any other things which is haram but allowed in paradise?

Comment: Well anything which is described in Quran. The point maybe if we should take these descriptions literally: For example having many wifes etc.

Answer (score 3):

One reason alcoholic drinks are prohibited in this world is that the bad things in it are more than the good in it.

> "They ask you about wine and gambling. Say, "In them is great sin and
>   [yet, some] benefit for people. But their sin is greater than their
>   benefit." [Quran 2:219](http://legacy.quran.com/2/219)

but the drinks in the hereafter would be free from the bad effects, it is mentioned in Quran

> "No headache will they have therefrom, nor will they be intoxicated -
>   " Quran [56: 19](http://legacy.quran.com/56/19).
>
> "No bad effect is there in it, nor from it will they be intoxicated. "
>   Quran [37: 47](http://legacy.quran.com/37/47)

Also, we have to keep in mind that the hereafter is entirely different creation and the worldly things are used just as an example.

> "The example of Paradise, which the righteous have been promised, is
>   [that] beneath it rivers flow. Its fruit is lasting, and its shade.
>   That is the consequence for the righteous, and the consequence for the
>   disbelievers is the Fire." [Quran 13:35](http://legacy.quran.com/13/35)

Answer (score 0):

Peace be upon you,
This Ayat means that Paradise will be full of pleasures. And one (who is Muslim) cannot take pleasure of wine in this world, but will be permitted to drink wine as much as he wish. As the Prophet Muhammad (S.A.W) has said: The World is the prison-house of the Believer and Paradise, of the infidel (hadith).
May Allah make us to drink wine of Paradise. Amin!

Comment: Can I ask you as well, are there any other things which is haram but will be practiced in paradise?